# URL rewriting taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, terms, get-posts

I'm trying to find solution for the following hours now and i don't know if this is applicable.

I have 1 **Custom Taxonomy "Years"** for **Post Type "Post (default)"**. The taxonomy has 2 Terms: **"2014"** and **"2015"**.

I have select some posts from category **"news"** to use the 2 different Taxonomy terms.

This shows me all posts for both taxonomy terms :

```
http://website.com/category/news/
```

When I want to display posts from category **"news"** with taxonomy term **"2014"** I use the following :

```
http://website.com/category/news/?years=2014
```

What I'm trying to do is instead of showing all posts from both taxonomy terms in  `http://website.com/category/news/` to display only **"2015" (term)** posts without using the slug **?years=2015** and without display **"2014"** posts

Taxonomy in functions:

```
function wptp_register_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'years', 'post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'              => 'Years',
                'singular_name'     => 'Year',
                'search_items'      => 'Search Year',
                'all_items'         => 'All Years',
                'edit_item'         => 'Edit Year',
                'update_item'       => 'Update',
                'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Year',
                'new_item_name'     => 'New Year',
                'menu_name'         => 'Years',
            ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'sort' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'years' ),
            'show_admin_column' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptp_register_taxonomy' );
```

Tried this in the category.php but didn't worked:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'years'    => '2015',
    );              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're using a reserved term "year".

https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Comment: Please explain what happens when you are using this term.